# Dplyr conditional logic count number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi there I'm trying to calculate the instances of an occurrence in my dataset. It's a very large dataset.

See below for the example:

```
     visitid   procedureid  collectiondatetime source status
     100       100.644      2016-12-03 17:20:00      N   COMP
     100       100.644      2017-09-21 12:00:00     RS   COMP
     100       100.644      2017-08-25 15:48:00      N   COMP
     100       100.644      2017-09-01 12:00:00     RS   COMP
     100       100.644      2017-08-23 10:31:00      N    CAN
     200       100.644      2017-09-01 14:00:00      N   COMP
```

I would like to determine if during a visit a procedure was cancelled (status= CAN) if the same procedure from same source is repeated at a later date and completed (status = COMP).
I would just like to summarize the number of times this occurs to determine if these cancelled occurrences are eventually corrected.

I've been away from R for a while and can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Maybe this will work better. I made a new dataset that has the following cases:

1. Multiple CAN before a CAN/COMP pair (visitid = 100)
2. Multiple COMP before a CAN/COMP pair (visitid = 200)
3. COMP without a CAN (visitid = 300)
4. CAN without a COMP (visitid = 400)

I'm assuming that regardless the number of CAN before a CAN/COMP pair, we will only consider it "corrected" once. So, in this dataset, we'd expect 2 corrections.

```
## read in data
text <- "visitid procedureid  collectiondatetime source status
100     100.644 2016-06-01 17:20:00      N    CAN
100     100.644 2016-12-03 17:20:00      N    CAN
100     100.644 2017-08-23 10:31:00      N    CAN
100     100.644 2017-08-25 15:48:00      N   COMP
200     100.644 2017-09-01 12:00:00     RS   COMP
200     100.644 2017-09-21 12:00:00     RS   COMP
200     100.644 2017-09-01 14:00:00     RS   COMP
200     100.644 2017-10-01 14:00:00     RS    CAN
200     100.644 2017-11-01 14:00:00     RS   COMP
300     100.644 2017-11-02 14:00:00     RS   COMP
400     100.644 2017-12-01 14:00:00     RS   CAN"
file <- textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8")
coln <- readLines(file, n = 1)
coln <- strsplit(coln, " ")[[1]]
coln <- coln[coln != ""]
on.exit(close(file))
df <- read.fwf(file = file, 
               widths = c(3, 12, 20, 7, 7),
               strip.white = TRUE,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df) <- coln
rm(coln, file, text)
```

We can then match each CAN with the next status. If the next status (by date/time) is COMP, then it is considered "corrected".

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
test <- df %>%
        arrange(visitid, procedureid, source, collectiondatetime) %>%
        group_by(visitid, procedureid, source) %>%
        mutate(corrected = ifelse(status == "COMP", NA, 
                                 ifelse(lead(status) == "COMP", TRUE, NA))) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        summarise(n = sum(corrected, na.rm = TRUE))
test
```

---

### Original Answer

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but here's an option. You could create pairs of CAN/COMP for each visit, procedure, and source. Then you could spread `proceduredatetime` by `status`, so you can check for pairs where the procedure was completed after it was cancelled.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test <- df %>%
    mutate(collectiondatetime = as.POSIXct(collectiondatetime)) %>%
    arrange(visitid, procedureid, source, collectiondatetime) %>%
    group_by(visitid, procedureid, source, status) %>%
    mutate(pair = row_number()) %>%
    spread(status, collectiondatetime) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(corrected = CAN < COMP)
as.data.frame(test)

# output
  visitid procedureid source pair                 CAN                COMP corrected
1     100     100.644      N    1 2017-08-23 10:31:00 2017-08-25 15:48:00      TRUE
2     100     100.644     RS    1                <NA> 2017-09-01 12:00:00        NA
3     100     100.644     RS    2                <NA> 2017-09-21 12:00:00        NA
4     200     100.644      N    1                <NA> 2017-09-01 14:00:00        NA
```

You can then get the sum of `corrected` to get the number of times the procedure was performed after cancelling:

```
sum(test$corrected, na.rm = TRUE)
```

*Note:* this assumes that for a given visit, procedure, and source, there is never a COMP procedure followed by a CAN and then a COMP. If this situation does occur, you could first remove COMP procedures performed before CAN procedures for each visit/procedure/source.

Comment: Thank you! My data does have COMP followed by CAN. I will try to remove the COMPs pre CAN.

Comment: @TomO Sure thing! If you want help, just add an example dataset with this situation

Comment: Here's what I did. I'm not sure if this makes sense. Basically used your code. Then.
  group_by (visitid, procedureid, source) %>%
  mutate(recollect = ifelse(CAN < lead(COMP), 1, NA)) %>%
  filter (!is.na(CAN)) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  group_by(procedureid, source, recollect) %>%
  summarise(n=n())

Comment: @TomO I think this will only work if you have exactly one COMP before a CAN/COMP pair

Comment: @TomO I updated my answer with a new option. Let me know if it works for you